# Env variable in Alias of VirtualHost

Tags: apache, alias, virtualhost

I have a  config in which I have Alias

```
<VirtualHost>
....
Alias /app/abcd "<path>"
...
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to use an environment variable to construct the path i.e

```
ENV_VAR/<rest of the path>
```

Is this possible? If yes, how to mention the env variable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able use the `${}` expansion notation with the environment variable name you want. Also, the Apache HTTP Server is a daemon process, so make sure that the desired environment variable is set by the OS before it forks off the server at boot, or before you run the `systemctl` command to restart the server.

Comment: So Alias /app/abcd "${ENV_VAR}/restOfThePath" should work, right? It doesn't seem to work. The env_var is set .bash_profile. Is that an issue?

Comment: Can you try that without the double quotes?

Comment: The Alias syntax itself has double quotes.